# How do you use ion-tabs with IonicVueRouter in Ionic (vue.js)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ionic-framework, vue-router

### Background

I am making a exercise warm-up app. I've conceptually segmented it into a workout tab and a settings tab. In a linear fashion the workout tab lets one pick a workout plan `ChooseWorkout.vue` then an exercise `ChooseLifts.vue` then the weight `ChooseWeight.vue` and it will display an appropriate warmup.

The aforementioned components are working correctly and link to each other in the correct linear fashion.

### What I want to do

I want to add tabbed navigation so a user can switch between the settings and the workout portion components of the app. The tabs I am making have a settings button and a workout button.

[Apps flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMe5O.png)

### The problem

When I integrate the ion-tabs the main tab buttons correctly display the desired 2 components (`ChooseWorkout.vue` and `Settings.vue`) when clicked. But **my problem** is the router no longer
works. So when I navigate from the `ChooseWorkout.vue` to the `ChooseLifts.vue` I get a blank screen, but the tabs at the bottom of the app are visible.

The url for this navigation is `http://localhost:8080/#/lifts/StrongLifts%205x5` (it works prior to the ion-tabs integration were `<ion-vue-router />` was solely used on `main.js`).

### Code

App.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <ion-app>
            <ion-tabs>
                <ion-tab tab="workout">
                    <ion-vue-router />
                </ion-tab>
                <ion-tab tab="settings">
                    <Settings />
                </ion-tab>
                <template slot="bottom">
                    <ion-tab-bar>
                        <ion-tab-button tab="workout">
                            <ion-icon name="body-outline" />
                            <ion-label>Workouts</ion-label>
                        </ion-tab-button>
                        <ion-tab-button tab="settings">
                            <ion-icon name="body-outline" />
                            <ion-label>Settings</ion-label>
                        </ion-tab-button>
                    </ion-tab-bar>
                </template>
            </ion-tabs>
        </ion-app>
    </div>
</template>
COPY TO CLIPBOARD    SELECT ALL
```

ChooseWorkout.vue

```
<template>
  <ion-page>
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar color="primary">
        <ion-title>Choose Workout</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content padding>
      <ion-list>
        <div v-for="workout in workouts" v-bind:key="workout">
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label>
                    <h1>{{workout.name}}</h1>
                    <p>{{workout.by}}</p>
                </ion-label>
                <router-link :to="{path:`lifts/${workout.name} `}">
                    <ion-button>Select</ion-button>
                </router-link>
            </ion-item>
        </div>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-page>
</template>

<script>
import { add } from "ionicons/icons";
import { addIcons } from "ionicons";

addIcons({
  "ios-add": add.ios,
  "md-add": add.md
});

export default {
    name: 'ChooseWorkout',
    data() {
        return {
            workouts: [
                {name: 'Starting Strength', by: 'Mark Rippetoe'},
                {name: 'StrongLifts 5x5', by: 'Mehdi'},
                {name: 'GreySkull LP', by: 'John Sheaffer'},
                {name: 'Max Single', by: 'n/a'}
            ]
        }
    },
    methods: {
    }
};
</script>

<style scope></style>
```

main.js

```
const router = new IonicVueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      redirect: "/workout"
    },
    {
      path: "/settings",
      name: "settings",
      component: Settings
    },
    {
      path: "/workout",
      component: ChooseWorkout
    },
    {
      path: "/lifts/:workout",
      component: ChooseLifts
    },
    {
      path: "/lifts/:workout/:excercise",
      component: ChooseWeight
    },
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your can use nested route in vue to accomplish that
https://ionicframework.com/docs/vue/navigation#working-with-tabs